# get windowController for a window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I able to find current opened window as :

```
NSWindow *currentWindow = [NSApp keyWindow];
```

But how can i know which class controls this window, i.e. Window controller for the above window?

Comment: Ideally start here: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
 NSLog(@"WindowController is : %@",[[currentWindow windowController] class]);
```

Comment: @Jay: by this method you get the class Name of window controller, isn't it?

Comment: Printing just about any object will also tell you its class (descriptions tend to look like `<SomeClassHere 0x2a4b6c8d optional other facts>`). Unless you're trying to see what kind of plist object you have, it's generally not worth the effort to explicitly print only the class.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I wonder, I am not printing any object, if I am wrong please excuse. I am printing the objects' class, i,e, something like PersonUpdateWindow, BoxWindow etc.

Comment: That's what Jay and I find strange. Printing the object also prints its class, so why print its class specifically?

Comment: @PeterHosey: As OP wanted to know the controllerClass for currentWindow. Should I use only `[currentWindow windowController]` ?

Comment: I would, but you're right, she did specify the class. Either way will work.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I doubt "she" is the real [Ileana D'Cruz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ileana_D'Cruz)